# How to use 2 lists to generate a list of results (in Java)?

Tags: java, performance, list

I have two JSON files, simplified they looks like:

**LIST 1**
[{AA,1}, {AJ,2}, {RA,5}, {ZA,15}, .... very long]

**LIST 2**
[{AA,0.1}, {AJ,0.2}, {ZA,1.0}, {RA,0.6}, .... very long]

Now what I need to do is convert these to objects (easy) and then generate a 3rd list by iterating through list 1 and looking up each code (AA, AJ, ZA, etc) in list 2 to get the value then multiply the two values to generate list 3.

So **List 3** (results) would look like:

[{AA,1 * 0.1}, {AJ,2 * 0.2}, {RA,5 * 0.6}, {ZA,15 * 1.0} ...etc]

**Problem:**

iterating through list 1 and for each code, iterate through list 2 to find it (and it might not even exist), is extremely inefficient.

What is a good approach to efficiently generate the results list?

**UPDATE**

I realized that it's not always a straight lookup for the value in list 2. When a code doesn't exist it's because it's necessary to use other codes to perform the calculation to get an equivalent:

**LIST 1** [{ZZ,99}]

**LIST 2** [{AZ,0.9}, {ZA,1.0}]

**Result list** [{ZZ, 99 * 0.9 * 1.0}]

Comment: Convert your list to map before matching then try .get method its pretty fast

Comment: with the clarification on what to do if the code isn't found in list 2, I suppose I need some kind of graph

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: (I don't know what is your list type, but the way to try I will show)

```
for(int i=0; i<list1.size() /*Or lisr1.lenght*/; i++) {
    int num1 = list1[i][1];
    int num2 = list2[i][1];
    String[] array = new String[2];
    array[0] = list1[i][0];
    array[1] = String.valueOf(num1*num2);
    list3[i] = larray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Hashmap using the letters as the key and the numbers as values.
Then you can itterate like this:

```
Hashmap<String, Double> listC = new Hashmap<String, Double>();
for (String key: listA.keySet()){
    if (listB.contains(key)){
        listC.put(key, listB.get(key)*listA.get(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use listA.entrySet() instead of iterating over the results of keySet and fetch the value for each key separately.

Just my two cents :)

Comment: It depends on the relation of found entries in a/found entries in b. listA.entrySet() fetches unnecessary values and creates unnecessary Objects. Nice idea though :) @grange